# Passing YAML key values to Python

Tags: python, yaml

I have a YAML file i.e. `test.yml` which looks like the following:

```
details:
       server1: abc.host.com
       port: 80
```

I am trying to read these keys and assign to a string using Python with code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import yaml

with open('test.yml', 'r') as cfg:
 yamlcfg=yaml.load(cfg)

str1 = "Hostname: " + (yamlcfg['details']['server1'])
print str1
```

When I run this code. I get error:

***`TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`***

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you add the yaml you wan to parse?

Comment: When I run that exact code, it prints `abc.host.com`. [You can try it yourself on repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SoftSwiftDisplaymanager).

Comment: @SmashGuy I have mentioned it in my question

Comment: Most likely your actual YAML file looks a little different, and actually has a dict of arrays of dicts, or an array of dicts of dicts, or something like that, instead of just a dict of dicts. That would give you this error. But we can't debug it without seeing (a) the actual example you're running, (b) the full error rather than just the description, and (c) what happens if you try `yamlcfg['details']` and `yamlcfg['details']['server1']` on separate lines so we know which one is failing.

Comment: And ideally, `print yamlcfg`, `print yamlcfg['detail']`, and `print yamlconfig['details']['server1']` on separate lines and show us the output (including the traceback from whichever one fails). More generally, see [mcve] for help on what should go into a question to make it possible for people to debug it for you.

Comment: ok i just tried print yamlcfg['details'] and it gives "TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable "

Comment: could this be a problem with my yaml file?

Comment: You are using `load()` which according to the PyYAML documentation can be unsafe. It is also completely unnecessary as you can almost always use  `safe_load()`, certainly for your code. You should also consider stopping the use of  `print` as a statement, Python 2.7 already supports print function (with `from __future__ import print_function)  and in 2020 Python2.7 is scheduled to be EOL (do you really want to wait getting rid of "bad" habits until you are forced to?).